# Select row only if ID is in excel file

Tags: python, pandas

I want to select rows from df only if their ID is in excel file. Why am I getting 0 rows?

```
df = pd.read_excel('df.xlsx')
df_with_status = pd.read_excel('df_status.xlsx')

df2=df[df['EFF_ID'].isin([df_with_status['ID']])]
```

I have got 0 rows but I should get more records.

Comment: Seems you have extra `[]` for what it should be `.isin(df_with_status['ID'])`. But even then I'm not sure; please see [mcve] to help others help you in case you need that.

Answer (score 2):

Not totally sure, but I think you have to remove the brackets at the isin() in this line

```
df2=df[df['EFF_ID'].isin([df_with_status['ID']])]
```

i.e. it should read

```
df2=df[df['EFF_ID'].isin(df_with_status['ID'])]
```

The reason is, that you are comparing the values against a list of data-frames instead of the list of values.

Comment: probably s/a list of data-frames/a 1-element list containing a Series/. (I didn't upvote, by the way.)